# what does NDB stand for in python datastore?

Tags: python, cloud, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-endpoints

I can't believe wiki doesn't have this answer.  I'm looking for NDB with respect to the google cloud platform and python, not non-directional beacon.
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/

Comment: Native Database API? Just guessing

Answer (score 9):

NDB stands for [Next Database](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/).

Comment: Because I linked to the original development location of it. And really, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks Saiyr. Should I update the Wikipedia article? I can't accept your answer since I'm a new contributor here and don't have a high enough reputation. The reason it matters to me is because it's the first thing I wonder about when I learn new terms: where they came from. It helps me remember them. Same reason I look up the etymology of words.

Comment: I don't know which article you are referring to, but [the index for NDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NDB) already says it stands for Next DB.

Comment: Yes, that is different. NDB in App Engine is a NoSQL database, so it's completely unrelated to MySQL.

Answer (score 3):

New DataBase according to this video from Google around min 10:13:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fQazhzcC-rg